# DDWRT firmware with asus rt-n12C

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I have a Asus RT-N12C which flashed with dd-wrt firmware http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N12 - broadcom_K26/dd-wrt.v24-18774_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini_RT-N12C1.trx ( a mini build). However ddwrt does not show Chillispot support in hotspot section. On further investigation i found that this is a mini version and does not contain the chillispot of the shelf.
Please guide me what should i do to install chillispot or somehow enable captive portal.

1) Can i install the other version of ddwrt firmware with chillspot of the shelf

2) Or is there some other way around.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can i install the other version of ddwrt firmware with chillspot of
>   the shelf

Yes. Update your firmware to a build which includes the chillispot feature.- [bin file](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/others/eko/BrainSlayer-V24-preSP2/2012/03-19-12-r18777/broadcom_K26/dd-wrt.v24-18774_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini_hotspot.bin) .
Download the .bin file and update firmware using your web gui.

However, with the mini-hotspot build, some features were also removed on this version ([refer here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F#K2.6_Build_Features)). You should check if there are features you wanted available(from the mini-build), rather than having chillispot enabled.